# Error at the line 51201: ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Tags: mysql, create-table, myisam, iso-8859-1, charset

i need help to knowledge where is problem when i want to restore backup my database from phpmyadmin  use bigdump and backup sql. file but this error :

> Error at the line 51201: ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
>
> Query:

```
CREATE TABLE `passwordhistory` (
`userid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`password` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`passworddate` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
KEY `userid` (`userid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

> MySQL: Invalid default value for 'passworddate'